# Fit ballon overlay in mapview

Tags: android, android-mapview, balloon

I have balloon popups showing in Android MapView when a user tap:s on specific points on the map. Depending on where the user taps the balloon does not always fit insize the MapView. I solve this now by using MapController.animateTo to always have the tapped point in center. However, this is not the way I prefer it to be. I would like to animate the MapView only so much that the balloon layout fits inside MapView.

Any tips on how this can be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to fit the balloon overlay is to override the dispatchDraw method, check the bounds of the display using getMeasuredWidth and getMeasuredHeight, and, draw the balloon such that it fits within the display area.

I am not sure if you have seen the [Android MapView Balloons project on github](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons). I have been using this code for a while and it is excellent, may be you can find some pointers to your problem from there.

Hope this helps.